# Facebook api: how to obtain current app namespace?

Tags: facebook

I want to create some open graph request for which I need current app namespace. How can I obtain current app namespace using javascript? I have several apps (with different namespaces) and I want to avoid setting constant in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `namespace` field of the app object:

```
GET /{app_id}?fields=namespace
```

where `{app_id}` is the current app's `id`, or with the JS SDK

```
FB.api('/{app_id}', {fields: 'namespace'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```